# Add Xml data to database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I have made this code to put in a database some webradio data from an xml witch is working, the problem is if the mp3 file as no album it messes up the data entry, can someone point a way to if $pieces[1] exists run the code and add the album if not don't do anything, and add the others in the right place.

```
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE;
$pieces = explode("-", $title);
$pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
$pieces[2] = trim($pieces[2]);
// performing sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) VALUES  ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time =   now(), album = VALUES(album)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: I had to downvote this question because the answer is so obvious you even said how to do it in your question.

Comment: John, i get stuck, i just want some ideias, iam new to php.

Comment: Iam sorry guys i just cant get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add : `if ($pieces[1]!="")` ?

```
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE;
$pieces = explode("-", $title);
$pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
$pieces[2] = trim($pieces[2]);
if ($pieces[1]!="")
{
// performing sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) VALUES  ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time =   now(), album = VALUES(album)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Comment: The problem is when there is not $pieces[1], $pieces[2] is $pieces[1].                                                                                          http://i.imgur.com/D5Kcbki.png

Comment: I see. So do `if (count($pieces)<3)`

Comment: I have reduced the problem to: if the $pieces[2] not exist it gives an error     "Notice: Undefined offset: 2 "

Comment: so do `if(isset($pieces[2]))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes that quite easy you just need to check if the value has been set.

```
if(isset($value_to_check))
{
    //true - your item has a value.
}
else
{
    //do somthing else.
}
```